# Basic table analysis SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have TABLE_A and i need to create TABLE_B. Rule: If YEAR_N >= YEAR_C, result will be 'A'. If YEAR_N < YEAR_C, result will be 'B'.

`TABLE_A

ID_N|YEAR_N|ID_C |YEAR_C |
25  |2015  | 1   |2013   |
28  |2013  | 1   |2015   |
250 |2010  | 3   |2001   |
400 |2008  | 2   |2008   |
460 |2001  | 3   |2016   |
840 |2000  | 2   |2005   |`

`TABLE_FINAL

ID_N|YEAR_N|ID_C |YEAR_C |RESULT      |
25  |2015  | 1   |2013   |A           |
28  |2013  | 1   |2015   |B           |
250 |2010  | 3   |2001   |A           |
400 |2008  | 2   |2008   |A           |
460 |2001  | 3   |2016   |B           |
840 |2000  | 2   |2005   |B           |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
select ta.*, case when YEAR_N >= YEAR_C then 'A'
                  else 'B'
             end as Result
from table_a ta
```